# JSP to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

My JSP has code as below..
`

```
           if ("print".equalsIgnoreCase(next))
    {
        out.print("var num=0;");
    }
    else if("none".equalsIgnoreCase(next)){
        out.print("");
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
    }
```

`

How can I move this to a Spring MVC controller..

I can have a ModelAndView returned for redirect with ModelAndView("redirect:myurl")

but what about the other two conditions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the response text is the job of the view. The controller's job is to prepare the data for the view. So, for example, you could do

```
if ("print".equalsIgnoreCase(next)) {
    modelAndView.addObject("mustPrint", true);
}
else if("none".equalsIgnoreCase(next)){
    modelAndView.addObject("mustPrint", false);
}
```

And in the JSP:

```
<c:if test="${mustPrint}">
    var num=0;
</c:if>
```

Comment: But then what about the redirection... should I use the c:url ? (the redirected url could be within same domain or another)

Comment: Redirecting or choosing the view is the job of the controller. I omitted it from my answer since you told you knew how to do it.

Comment: Yeah ..but what i was looking for ..single controller that can help me migrate this JSP code..